# Accessing Meteor local web server from another local device on Mac 10.8

Tags: macos, webserver, meteor

I am working on a Meteor website and conveniently, it will run on localhost with the simple command, `meteor`. However, I want to be able to access this website from other computers on the local network. The main reason I want to do this is for viewing and testing the app on mobile.

I am running Mac Mountain Lion 10.8, and they got rid of some of the convenient Personal Web Sharing pref panes. Everything else I have seen online deals with setting up your own server, but all I want to do is grant access from other local device...

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find out your ip address  192.168.1.12  (mac system prefs/network)
start meteor in your project on a port (default 3000)
from another comp on network, browse 192.168.1.12:3000

Comment: do you have force-ssl? if yes, you may want to run 'mrt remove force-ssl' to remove the package first.