# Meteor app runnning on localhost (hosted on MacBook) does not work from other devices

Tags: macos, meteor

I have a Meteor app running on my MacBook with OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitain)

I'm trying to test my Meteor app on different **devices connected to the same Wireless Network as the Mac**. For that I ran `ifconfig` and took note of the Mac's ip (*192.168.2.109*). When I go to *192.168.2.109:3000* on the Mac, it works. However, it does not work in any other device.

**There's also another important point**: I ran the very same project from on another machine (using Ubuntu 14.04) and everything went fine. I was able to access the app from all the devices connected to the network.

Moving on, I also tried to run the app like this too (but didn't work): `meteor --port=http://192.168.2.109:3000 --mobile-server=http://192.168.2.109`

I checked the OSX Firewall and it's disabled.

I tried to follow the anwsers from these questions:

- https://forums.meteor.com/t/running-mobile-app-in-device-problems-connecting-with-server/4197/12
- [Accessing Meteor local web server from another local device on Mac 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601961/accessing-meteor-local-web-server-from-another-local-device-on-mac-10-8)
- [Meteor - accessing the app using public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276097/meteor-accessing-the-app-using-public-ip)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213332/how-to-access-web-dev-servers-running-on-localhost-with-non-standard-ports-from

But none of them worked.

Has anyone experienced this before? Some guidance would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the environment variable ROOT_URL. So in your case, CLI input should be:
`ROOT_URL="http://192.168.2.109" meteor --port 3000`

If you are just using the default port of 3000, you don't need the --port 3000, I showed it in case you wanted to use a different port.

You can read more about environment variables here: [Meteorpedia: Environment Variables](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables) It should be noted that this is an older resource not up to date with all the latest specifications. However, my search of the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) didn't reveal the specific answer to your question.

Comment: Hi @bearcanrun, thanks for the answer. I tried it but it still doesn't work. Still trying!

Comment: Hello again, @bearcanrun. I tried your suggestion again, and it suddenly works! Maybe I was facing some kind of LAN configuration trouble the other day. If I find it out, I'll be sure to post it here. Thanks.